# Quick path jumping

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, paths

I was just at a lecture, where I noticed the lecturer using a command (probably aliased) to jump to a specific folder.

Example:

```
~/code$ j sciproj
~/projects/sciproj2011/$
```

This looked quite slick, so I started wondering:

Is this a standard utility, and if so, what is the name?

I have two theories as to how it works:

1. It can both create, delete and jump to aliases directly from the command-line in the style of the example, without having to set up aliases in a configuration file or script or whatnot manually.
2. It searches the home directory for a folder matching the name and jumps to it.

The second option seems a bit slow, however, so the first would be preferred.

Comment: https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an addition to  sagarchalise's comment:

It's in natty: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/autojump

Should work in older releases as well.

Comment: Excellent; looks like the thing he was using.

Comment: It's not in maverick, is it?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function j() { for dir in ~/projects/$@*; do if [ -d $dir ]; then cd "$dir"; fi; done ;}
```

It finds the nearest possible match. So say I have a dir listing like this:

```
~/projects/
~/projects/apples/
~/projects/apples-and-pears/
~/projects/cabbage/
```

`j a` will match both `apples*` dirs but as `apples-and-pears` is the later, it will cd into that last, and that's where you'll end up (the flaw in this function). `j c` will put you in `~/projects/cabbage/`.

Bung that into a terminal to test it and when you're happy, just plonk it on the end of `~/.bashrc`.

Edit: I've also been playing around making a `find` variant but it's not as good (slower and less accurate). Feel free to hack around with it though.

```
function j() { cd $(find ~/projects -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$@*"); }
```

Comment: It's gonna be reeeaaaally slooooww...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use `popd`, `pushd` and `dirs` to jump between some folders. But in your case, it's some custom alias which you can define in your ~/.bash_profile file.

In example:

```
# Change dir via find
# Usage: cdf (dir)
cdf() {
  pushd $(find . -name $1)
}
```

And then `cdf some_dir` will jump into folder ignoring the sub-dirs.

Live example to search for exact folder names (ignore prompt):

```
~/$ cdf() { pushd $(find . -name $1); }
~/$ mkdir -p ab/cd/ef/gh/ij/kl
~/$ cdf kl
    ~/ab/cd/ef/gh/ij/kl ~/
~/$ pwd
     ~/ab/cd/ef/gh/ij/kl
kl$ popd # We're going back to our previous folder.
~/$ pwd
    ~/
```

To similar alias for folders containing a partial text:

```
cdf() { pushd $(find . -name \*$1\*); }
```

Example [.bash_profile](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile) file.